# Axis stroke in anystock?

Tags: anychart

I am trying to change the axis stroke and axis font color in an anystock chart. I tried using the normal method for anycharts and it didn't work.
Is there a way to change these values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably looking for these methods:

https://api.anychart.com/7.14.3/anychart.core.stock.Plot#yAxis
https://api.anychart.com/7.14.3/anychart.core.stock.Plot#xAxis

Here is a sample: https://jsfiddle.net/vmgwemws/

```
  chart.plot(0).yAxis().stroke("Red");
  chart.plot(0).yAxis().ticks().stroke("Red"); 
  chart.plot(0).yAxis().labels().fontColor("Red");
  chart.plot(0).yAxis().labels().fontFamily("Courier");

  chart.plot(0).xAxis().labels().fontColor("Red");
  chart.plot(0).xAxis().labels().fontFamily("Courier");

  chart.plot(0).xAxis().minorLabels().fontColor("Red");
  chart.plot(0).xAxis().minorLabels().fontFamily("Courier");

  chart.plot(0).xAxis().background("Gray 0.5");
```

Comment: This seems to only be partially working on my chart. I'm not sure what's wrong.
<a href="https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3CTXkp6vNkaaFdjOEh2RFFKUTQ/view?usp=sharing">Screenshot</a>
Why would only some of the labels turn out red?

Comment: @Joshacola did you add both   chart.plot(0).xAxis().minorLabels().fontColor("Red");
and

Comment: and  chart.plot(0).xAxis().labels().fontColor("Red"); ?

Comment: No! Thank you so much! I didn't realize that those were considered minor labels.